# Differences in instance_eval behaviour between Ruby 1.9.1 and 1.8.6?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ruby-1.8

I noticed that class variables @@my_class var are now looked up in the context of the instance_eval'd object in Ruby 1.9.1 whereas this was not the case in Ruby 1.8.6.

What are some other differences in behaviour of instance_eval for Ruby 1.9.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't list them all, but I know that there are some changes in constant lookup. In 1.8, constant lookup was in the callers scope, while it is in the blocks scope in 1.9.

```
FOO = "hi"

class Something
  FOO = "bye"

  def self.handle(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

p Something.handle { FOO }
# "hi" on 1.8, "bye" on 1.9
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect. Try running the code in 1.9 and 1.8, the output is same.

Comment: It was probably accurate for the version of 1.9 that was available in 2009 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it [at least currently] doesn't return self, either.